# How can I add elements to a list in a for loop and print a single list?

Tags: python, list

**I got confused while solving this task:**

In a factory a printer prints labels for boxes. For one kind of boxes the printer has to use colors which, for the sake of simplicity, are named with letters from a to m.

The colors used by the printer are recorded in a control string. For example a "good" control string would be aaabbbbhaijjjm meaning that the printer used three times color a, four times color b, one time color h then one time color a...

Sometimes there are problems: lack of colors, technical malfunction and a "bad" control string is produced e.g. aaaxbbbbyyhwawiwjjjwwm with letters not from a to m.

You have to write a function printer_error which given a string will return the error rate of the printer as a string representing a rational whose numerator is the number of errors and the denominator the length of the control string. Don't reduce this fraction to a simpler expression.

The string has a length greater or equal to one and contains only letters from a to z.

**My sample code:**

```
s = 'aaabbbbhaijjjmz'
li = []
# 97 to 109

for i in s:
    i = ord(i)
    
    if i in range(97, 109):
        
        print(0/len(s))
    
    else:
        for x in s:
            x = ord(x)
        if x > 109:
            li.append(x)
            print(x)
```

**Problem:**

I want to challenge this problem in the following steps. I want to convert the string to ASCII and then find the range from a to m. My program then reads if there is an accepting range in a given string or not. If the string is in the acceptable range then it prints 0/len(s).
However, if the program reads an unacceptable string, the task is to find an amount of errors so, if the range is greater than 109(in ASCII) then I want those elements to be added to the list. But when I'm doing this, my program prints two lists. Please help me out

Comment: What do you expect the result of `0/len(s)` to be? Why?

Comment: Anyway, the program doesn't print multiple lists; it prints the same list at multiple points in time. You should be able to think of the reason why this happens. Hint: how do loops work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the function `printer_errors()` which you described. It calculates the fraction `number_of_errors / total_number_of_colors`.

```py
s = 'aaabbbbhaijjjmz'

def printer_error(s):

    # count erroneous characters
    n_errors = 0
    for i in s:
        if ord(i) not in range(97, 109):
            n_errors = n_errors + 1
            
    # calculate fraction of erroneous characters
    return n_errors / len(s)
    
print(printer_error(s))
```

Output:
`0.13333333333333333`

Comment: Cheers, that helped

Comment: Consider to accept and vote for the answer if it helped. That's the preferred way over 'thanks'-comments.

Comment: sorry bro, I did not have certain reputation to put a tick next to your post :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to convert letters to ASCII codes, compare them directly. You don't need to add something in a for loop to a list. If you want only a final error ratio, than the following one-liner will be enough:

```
print(f"{sum(not 'a'<=x<='m' for x in s)}/{len(s)}")
```

You can also modify it to use for loop, if you want, and append whatever you want:

```
count, li = 0, []
for x in s:
    if not 'a' <= x <= 'm':
        count += 1
        li.append(x)
print(f'{count}/{len(s)}')
print(x)
```

In the first approach we `print` an f-string. F-string is in simple words a usual string, where all literals or code pieces in curly braces are evaluated and then inserted into the string. `print(f'a {b}+{c**2}')` is an equivalent for `print('a ', b, '+', c**2, sep='')`, but to avoid spaces I need last argument, so f-string is faster to write and easier to understand. Then I use sum() - built-in function to sum all iterable elements. Inner object is a generator - it's similar to for loop, but a bit faster, more memory efficient and shorter. It evaluates `not 'a'<=x<='m'` for each element x of s and yields it one-by-one to sum. Comparison result is evaluated as int in sum, not is used to indicate letters not from range a..m. Two-sided comparison is useful feature in this case.

Second code snippet does the same, but in a loop. Omit all `li` references, if you don't need a list of mistakes. We initialize a counter and go through string, increasing counter every time when we meet a letter not from a..m range.

Comment: I find your solution a bit hard to read, is there any chance you could simplify your code? I started to learn python so, it's not a problem in your code:)

Comment: Added explanation to answer.